# how to use Wildcard in Intellij IDEA arguments

Tags: intellij-idea, go

I use try add arguments in run configuration.

I add `master sequential pg-*.txt`. But when I start running. the error come out.

```
/usr/local/go/bin/go run /home/asus/dev/6.824/src/main/wc.go master sequential pg-*.txt
master: Starting Map/Reduce task wcseq
panic: open pg-*.txt: no such file or directory
```

But I use the command in terminal is OK.

```
~/dev/6.824/src/main$ /usr/local/go/bin/go run /home/asus/dev/6.824/src/main/wc.go master sequential pg-*.txt
master: Starting Map/Reduce task wcseq
Merge: read mrtmp.wcseq-res-0
Merge: read mrtmp.wcseq-res-1
Merge: read mrtmp.wcseq-res-2
master: Map/Reduce task completed
```

I think the problem is the Wildcard.So how to use Wildcard in Intellij IDEA arguments?

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question, but it may help some people who ended here like me : 
To set several glob patterns in intellij's config, such as `Code Style/Do not format` : use `;` for example : `*json;*md`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The string `pg-*.txt` is referred to as a [glob](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/glob.7.html) pattern. In the latter example you are asking your shell to execute a given command which includes your glob pattern. The shell evaluates the glob pattern as a pre-processing step. The Go program then receives a list of files that have been matched by the pattern.

You will have to update your IntelliJ settings to run the program within a shell as described in [**In JetBrains IDEs (e.g. CLion, IntelliJ), external tools cannot use globbing patterns**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35120549/in-jetbrains-ides-e-g-clion-intellij-external-tools-cannot-use-globbing-pat) Stack Overflow question. By evaluating the initial go run command within a shell process your program will receive the arguments as expected.

An alternative solution is to treat all your arguments as glob patterns and utilize the [`filepath.Glob(pattern string) (matches []string, err error)`](https://golang.org/pkg/path/filepath/#Glob) function to manually expand on the provided argument. This strategy requires a little more preprocessing from your program but is more tolerant to the runtime environment. You can see an example of this kind of expansion in this [**Go Playground Example**](https://play.golang.org/p/A-I1ohtgie).