# clion wildcard expansion in argv array

Tags: c++, glob, clion

The question is more or less the same as asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39684417/how-to-use-wildcard-in-intellij-idea-arguments). But I would like to ask what is the way to do it in 2020 for cpp development with clion. I would like to achieve the same in clion as I achieve while running the program in the console. Having a folder with multiple .txt files and a program my-pgram that lists all .txt files, it would be nice if `./my-program *.txt` in clion would also list all .txt files as it does if the executable is run in the shell.

Comment: So the problem is that normally the shell does the wildcard expansion but (I assume) CLion does not. So what kind of solution are you expecting? Do you want some technique to make CLion do the wildcard expansion or are you willing to change your program to do wildcard expansion? Those are two very different questions. Which one to you want answered?

Comment: "the problem is that normally the shell does the wildcard expansion but (I assume) CLion does not" - correct. I would like CLion to do the expansion, so I can use it for development more efficiently.